# Irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$

Tags: abstract-algebra

How can I prove that $2+\sqrt{-5}$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$? I tried to show by $2+\sqrt{-5}=(a+b\sqrt{-5})(c+d\sqrt{-5})$ but I could not get a contradiction.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If $2+\sqrt{-5} = AB$, then $9=N(2+\sqrt{-5})=N(A)N(B)$ where $$N(u+v\sqrt{-5})=(u+v\sqrt{-5})(u-v\sqrt{-5})=u^2+5v^2$$ is the norm.  If $N(A)=1$ or $N(B)=1$, then $A$ is a unit or $B$ is a unit, respectively.  So if $2+\sqrt{-5}$ is reducible, there must be $A,B$ with $N(A)=N(B)=3$.  Show that there can't be any $A$ such that $N(A)=3$.

Comment: how do you show correctly that there can't be any $A$ such that $N(A) = 3$?

Comment: Show there are no integer solutions to $u^2+5v^2=3$. @ALannister Clearly, $v$ must be zero, or $u^2+5v^2\geq 5$. So now you need $u^2=3$.

Comment: logically, I thought that's how it should be done, but since I'd never actually seen anyone do it before, I wasn't sure. Thank you!

Comment: So by this logic, all elements of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ of norm $9$ are irreducible?

Comment: Yes, but there really aren't that many elements of norm $9.$ $\pm 2\pm\sqrt{-5}$ and $\pm 3.$ @Vadim

Answer (score 14):

While you already have a very big hint, I thought it would be worthwhile to expand a bit on the conceptual motivation. Generally, when studying factorization theory in rings of algebraic integers one can deduce a *great deal* from studying the factorizations of their corresponding norms - which form a "simpler" multiplicative submonoid of the integers (cf. the [method of simpler multiples](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3224776/242)). This is true simply because the norm map is *multiplicative* $\,N(xy) = N(x)N(y)\,$ so it preserves many properties related to factorization. For example, in many favorable contexts (e.g. Galois) a number ring enjoys unique factorization iff its monoid of norms does. For references (Bumby and Dade, Lettl, Coykendall) see my [sci.math post on 19 Dec 2007](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/plIhy9-f2Ns/m/QglgftJL0uIJ) partially excerpted below (see the post for AMS reviews of related interesting papers). See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/680114/242) for analogous methods for factoring polynomials via their "simpler" evaluations.

---

> Let $d\,$ be a squarefree positive integer, with $\,d > 1,\,$ and let $R\,$ be
> the ring of integers of the real quadratic number field $\,\Bbb Q(\sqrt d).\,$ Let $\,z \in R\,$ be such that $\,N(z)\,$ is composite.
>
> Question $(1)\!:\  $ Must $z$ be reducible in $R\,?$

No, e.g. inert primes $p\,$ have $\, N(p) = p^2.$

A number ring is a PID iff its atoms have prime power norms,
i.e. exactly one prime $\,p\,$ occurs in norms of an irreducible element
$\,N(q) = p^n,\,  p,q\,$ atoms in resp. rings. The proof is easy.

> Question $(2)\!:\ $ If there exist nonunits $\,x,y \in R\,$ such that
> $\,N(x) N(y) = N(z),\,$  must $\,z\,$ be reducible in $\,R\,?$

No, e.g.  $\,x = y = 3,\,  z = 5 + 2 \sqrt{-14}.$

Bumby and Dade [2] classified those quadratic number fields $K$ where
reducibility depends only on the norm. Denoting the class group by $H,$
they proved that $K$ satisfies this property iff

(a) $\ H\,$ has exponent $2,\,$  or
(b) $\ H\,$ is odd, $\,$  or
(c) $\ K\,$ is real with positive fundamental unit and the $2$-Sylow subgroup
of the narrow class group is cyclic.

Note the above example $\,\Bbb Q(\sqrt{-14})$ has class group $\,K = {\rm C}(4)\,$ with exponent $4$.

See Coykendall's [paper [1]](http://www.math.ndsu.nodak.edu/faculty/coykenda/paper3.pdf) for a recent discussion of related results
and generalizations.

[1] Jim Coykendall. Properties of the normset relating to the class group.
http://www.ams.org/proc/1996-124-12/S0002-9939-96-03387-4
http://www.math.ndsu.nodak.edu/faculty/coykenda/paper3.pdf

[2] 35 #4186  10.65 (12.00)
Bumby, R. T.  [Irreducible integers in Galois extensions.](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/pacific-journal-of-mathematics/volume-22/issue-2/Irreducible-integers-in-Galois-extensions/pjm/1102992192.full)
Pacific J. Math.  22  1967 221--229.