# Find irreducible but not prime element in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}]$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have tried various numbers of the form $a+b\sqrt{5},\ a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$, but cannot find the one needed.

I would appreciate any help.

*Update:* I have found that $q=1+\sqrt{5}$ is irreducible. Now if I show that 2 is not divisible by $q$ in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}]$ then $2\cdot2 = (\sqrt{5}-1)(\sqrt{5}+1)$ and I'm done. Can it be shown without use of norm ?

*The last update:* I have written the equation $(\sqrt{5}+1)(x\sqrt{5}+y)=2$ and have deduced that the equation has no integer solutions. Thanks to all who helped.

Comment: Why don't you want to use the norm?

Comment: Indeed.  Especially since "using the norm" is a bit of an overstatement -- all you're doing is multiplying by $\overline{q}$.

Comment: @AlexBecker because then I need to prove that there is a norm on the ring and the ring is integral.

Comment: **Try** to divide $2$ by $\sqrt{5}+1$. So write $\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}+1}$, and rationalize the denominator.

Comment: @CamMcLeman question is about $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}]$, not $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$.

Comment: Let's assume that bar means Galois conjugate :). But I think André's suggestion is simpler.

Comment: It is actually easier to show that $2$ is irreducible, and that it does not divide $1+\sqrt{5}$ (or $1-\sqrt{5}$)...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** $(\sqrt{5}+1)(\sqrt{5}-1)=4$

Added: (after the OP's edit) When it comes to showing that $\sqrt{5}+1$ does not divide $2$, note that 
$$\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}+1}=\frac{2(\sqrt{5}-1)}{(\sqrt{5}+1)(\sqrt{5}-1)}.$$

Comment: I have shown that by another method. Maybe It's the same as rationalization of denominator.

Comment: @Sergey Filkin: Your method works just fine. Both your method and rationalizing solve the problem of finding *rationals* $x$ and $y$ such that $2/(\sqrt{5}+1)=x+y\sqrt{5}$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: the norm map is absolutely *crucial* here. Because it is multiplicative, taking norms preserves the multiplicative structure and transfers divisibility problems from quadratic number fields to simpler integer divisibility problems (in a multiplicative submonoid of $\mathbb Z$). In this case the transfer is *faithful*, i.e. an element of your quadratic number ring is irreducible iff its norm is irreducible in the monoid of norms. Similarly, in many favorable cases, a quadratic number ring will have unique factorization iff its monoid of norms does.

For much more on this conceptual viewpoint see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/95015). It is *crucial* to understand this conceptual viewpoint in order to master (algebraic) number theory. Do not settle for ad-hoc proofs when much more enlightening conceptual proofs are easily within grasp.

Comment: I have solved the problem without use of norm. See my edited post.

Comment: Also it's not true that if an element of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}]$ is irreducible, then it's norm is irreducible. Take $1+3\sqrt{5}$, it's irreducible, but its norm is not.

Comment: But I agree with you that it's enlightening to apply to conceptual proofs instead of low level proofs.

Comment: @Sergey The irreducibility of the norm occurs in the monoid of all norms of elements of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}]$. Since this is a *proper* multiplicative submonoid of $\mathbb Z$, the meaning of "irreducible" may differ from that in $\mathbb Z$. Please see the linked post and its references,.

Comment: this topic is deeper than I thought. Thank you for the link.