# Find an integral domain $D$ containing an irreducible element $p$ such that $D/\langle p \rangle$ is not a field.

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Find an integral domain $D$ containing an irreducible element $p$ such that $D/\langle p \rangle$ is not a field.

I'm working on homework. I think I need to find p such that the ideal generated by $p$ is not maximal. So I think I need an integral domain which is not a PID. If $p$ did not have to be irreducible, I think I could use the ideal genrated by $x^2 \in \mathbb Z[x]$. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why not take $x$ instead of $x^2$?

Comment: I was thinking that the ideal generated by x was maximal.

Comment: @OLP: $\mathbb{Z}[x]/<x>\simeq \mathbb{Z}$ which is not a field, so $<x>$ is not maximal.

Comment: @OLP, it depends on what $k$ is. If $k = \mathbb Z$ and you're looking at $k[x]$, $(x) \subsetneq (2, x)$ and so it's not maximal.

Comment: Thanks, both of you. This stuff is all so new. I, still learning to use the higher level theorems and to stop thinking in terms of manipulating elements.

Comment: @OLP Careful, $x^2$ is reducible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try $D=K[x,y]$ and $p=x$, where $K$ is an integral domain (a field, for instance).

Comment: Thanks! Would you happen to have suggestions that involve adjoining only one element? I'm not so familiar with adjoins more than one element and our class hasn't touched on it much. I am grateful for the help, in any case.

Comment: @OLP, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducible_element#Example and http://math.stackexchange.com/q/106681/589.