# Finding an irreducible element which is not prime in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

The problem is in the title. I have spent hours to guess the answer (using norm $N(a + b\sqrt{5}) = a^2 - 5b^2$ for checking irreducibility, of course). I also proved that $a^2 - 5b^2 \neq 1$ unless $b=0$, but I don’t know if I am going to need it.

I have seen something similar in some book long time ago. There was a ring $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$, though. And the author didn’t explain how did he find it. He rather just gave and example.

Edit: althoug my question has already arised [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/106681/find-irreducible-but-not-prime-element-in-mathbbz-sqrt5?rq=1), there wasn’t explained why $1 + \sqrt{5}$ is irreducible. I failed to check it.

Comment: I am sorry, I just found out that it’s a duplicate. I couldn’t find it when I was making my own question, though.

Comment: It's OK. Perhaps you could attach the link of the question that already existed.