# Cardinality of the quotient ring $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2-3,2x+4)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

This problem is from a practice exam I was working on.

> What is the cardinality of the quotient $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2-3,2x+4)$ ?

**Thoughts**. If I find a ring that is easier to handle then this then I can go from there. So I think this is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]/(x^2-3,x+2)$. And then I am stuck.

Am I correct so far? What should I be looking to do from here?

Thanks for your time and your answers.

Comment: Use long division of the elements of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ by $x^3-3$. Notice that we can do this and stay in integer coefficients, since the leading coefficient of $x^3-3$ is $1$. You get representatives being the possible remainders, i.e. $ax^2+bx+c$. Now you need to separate in cases, depending on the parity of $a,b,c$ to 'divide' by $2x-4$ as much as possible, these remainders. The remainders in the different cases give you representatives for the elements of the quotients.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But why divide by $x^3-3$. One of the factors are $x^2-3$? Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, divide by $x^2-3$. I misread the exponent.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your start is good  as long as you can show that $2\in(x^2-3,2x+4)$. Fortunately this is the case: $x(2x+4)-2(x^2-3)=4x+6$ and $2(2x+4)-(4x+6)=2$. (Actually one can show that $(x^2-3,2x+4)=(x^2+1,2)$.) So $$\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2-3,2x+4)\simeq \mathbb{Z}_2[x]/(x^2+1)$$ and this ring has $4$ elements.

Comment: thanks for the answer. So to show the equality of the two ideals I imply show that the respective generator is in the other ideal and visa versa and I'm done right?

Answer (score 10):

A slight modification of YACP's answer:

If a ring contains an element $x$ satisfying $x^2=3$ and $2x=-4$, then we get $6=2x^2=-4x=8$, hence $2=0$, and the second relation becomes superflous. This shows that $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2-3,2x+4)=\mathbb{Z}/2[x]/(x^2-3)$.

I just want to emphasize that you don't have to come up with clever linear combinations of the generators of the ideal. Just compute *inside the quotient ring*!

(In fact, as usual, you can also see this as an application of the Yoneda Lemma: The algebraic manipulations above show that $\hom(\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2-3,2x+4),-) \cong \hom(\mathbb{Z}/2[x]/(x^2-3),-)$.)

Comment: Very nice. I like your answer.

Comment: @RohanK More *conceptually:* $\,2(2\!+\!x)=0\,\Rightarrow\, 2 = 0\,$ by cancelling unit $\,2\!+\!x\,$ [by scaling by its inverse $\,2\!-\!x;\,$  intutively it's just $(2\!+\!\sqrt 3)(2\!-\!\sqrt 3) = 1,\,$ cf. my answer]

Answer (score 5):

**Hint** $\ $ Note $\,(2\!-\!x)(2\!+\!x) = (2\!-\!\sqrt 3)(2\!+\sqrt 3)=1\,$ in $\ \Bbb Z[x]/(\color{#0a0}{x^2\!-\!3})\cong \,\Bbb Z[\sqrt 3],\, $ therefore, since $\ 2\!+\!x\,$ in a *unit* $\!\bmod \color{#0a0}{x^2\!-\!3},\,$ we can cancel  it from the generator $\,\color{#c00}2(2\!+\!x)\, $ of $I,\,$ yielding

$\qquad\ \ I = (\color{#0a0}{x^2\!-\!3},\,\color{#c00}2(2\!+\!x)) = (x^2\!-\!3,\color{#c00}2) = ((x\!+\!1)^2,2),\  $ so $\,\ \Bbb Z[x]/I = \Bbb Z_2[x]/((x\!+\!1)^2)$

---

**Remark** $\ $ Alternatively we can do the cancellation *purely equationally* as below

$\bmod I\!:\,\ \color{#0a0}{x^2\equiv 3},\,\ \color{}2(\color{}{2\!+\!x)\equiv 0} \,\Rightarrow\,0\equiv \color{}2(2\!+\!x)(2\!-\!x) \equiv 2(4\!-\!\color{#0a0}{x^2})\equiv 2(4\!-\!\color{#0a0}3) \equiv \color{#c00}2\ $

More generally when studying algebraic number rings [we can often deduce much  by taking *norms*](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/95015/242) (e.g. above we used: $\,\alpha = 2+\sqrt{3}\,$ is a unit since its norm $\,N(\alpha ) = \alpha \bar\alpha  = 1)$.

---

The resulting quotient ring is $\,\cong \Bbb Z_2[\epsilon]/(\epsilon^2),\,$ the ring of [dual numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3178/242) over $\,\Bbb Z_2.\,$ Such dual number rings prove useful for algebraically modelling derivatives, tangent spaces, etc.

---

The hint amounts to [*Euclid's Lemma* in ideal form](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/252748/242), i.e.

**Lemma** $\,\ \color{#0a0}{(a,b)=1}\,\Rightarrow\, (a,bc) = (a,c)\ $

**Proof** $\ \ \ (a,bc) = (a,ac,bc) = (a,\color{#0a0}{(a,b)}c) = (a,c)$