# Decompose 6 into irreducible elements in Z[5i]

Tags: abstract-algebra

We are in the ring $ \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$

$$
6 = 2\times3=(1+\sqrt{-5}) (1-\sqrt{-5}) 
$$

My question is how to show $2,3,(1+\sqrt{-5}), (1-\sqrt{-5}) $ are irreducible elements of the ring.

Comment: I corrected $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-6}]$ to $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$ in the first statement in the question to make it consistent with the rest. If this is wrong, do edit again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the norm on the ring,

$$N(x+y\sqrt{-5}) = x^2 + 5y^2.$$

You have $N(a\cdot b) = N(a)\cdot N(b)$. That constrains the possible divisors, and allows you to conclude that all divisors of e.g. $1+\sqrt{-5}$ are units or associated to $1+\sqrt{-5}$.

Comment: Thanks :) Is this a general way to show something is irreducible ?

Comment: In rings where you have a ($\mathbb{Z}$-valued, or with values in another nice enough similar ring) norm (that you can reasonably compute), yes. It's of course only practical when the norm of the elements in question has few enough prime divisors.

Comment: @Daniel Only in certain number rings does irreducibility depend only on the norm. But the monoid of norms does reflect many of the properties of the number ring - see [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/95015/242) for further discussion and references.

Comment: @Bill Of course it does in general not depend only on the norm. But the prime factorisation of the norm considerably restricts the search space, that's the point.

Comment: @SamC My prior comment was meant for you. Daniel: one can say much more - see the papers I reference there.