# Prove if $z \in \mathbb{Z}{[i]}$ such that $N(z)$ is a prime number then $z$ is irreducible.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, integral-domain

Let $N:\mathbb{Z}{[i]} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ be defined as $N(a+bi)= a^2+b^2$. Prove  if $z \in \mathbb{Z}{[i]}$ such that $N(z)$ is a prime number then $z$ is irreducible.

I understand that by definition of function $N$ that the result of $N(z)= \text{prime}$. I also know that due to ring structure primes and irreducibility are related but not the same thing. How do I formally show that $z=ab$ for $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}{[i]}$ implies that either $a$ or $b$ is a unit?

Comment: Do you mean the Gaussian integers, $\mathbb Z[i]$? Because the subscript is confusing...

Comment: Yes, this is how they are notationally described in my book. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 7):

Suppose that you have $ z=uv $, then $ N(z)=N(u) N(v) $, since $ N(z) $ is prime by hyphotesis, we get that either $ N(u) $ or $ N(v) $ is equal to $1$. Wlog, suppose that $ N(v)=1$, so if we write $ v=c+di $, we get $ c^2+d^2=1$. From that is easy to deduce that $ v $ is a unit. Therefore $ z $ is irreducible.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $ $  If $\,x\mapsto  Nx\, $ is $\rm\color{#c00}{multplicative}$ and $\,\color{#0a0}{x\mid Nx}\,$ then $\,Na$ irreducible $\,\Rightarrow\, a$ irreducible, since

$\ \ a = bc\,\color{#c00}\Rightarrow\, Na = Nb\, Nc,\ $ so $\,Nb\,$ or $\,Nc\,$ is a unit, say $Nc.\,$ Then $\,\color{#0a0}{c\mid Nc}\mid 1$ so $\,c\,$ is unit.

Yours is special case $Na = aa' = $ norm of $a$

**Remark** $ $ The key idea is that multiplicative maps preserve multiplicative properties (which is brought to the fore in *divisor theory*). Above we pullback the "atom" (irreducible) property  along the multiplicative norm map $\,N$.

In fact much of the multiplicative structure of a number ring is reflected in its monoid of norms. For example, in many favorable contexts (e.g. Galois) a number ring enjoys unique factorization iff its monoid of norms does. See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/95015/242) for further discussion, including literature references (Bumby and Dade, Lettl, Coykendall).