# If $N(z)=a^2+b^2 =\text{ prime } \in \Bbb{Z}$ show $\Bbb{Z}[i]/(a+bi)$ is a field of prime order.

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $N(z)=a^2+b^2 =\text{ prime }\in \Bbb{Z}$ 
show $$\frac{\Bbb{Z}[i]}{(a+bi)}$$ is a field of prime order.

---

from [Prove if $z \in \mathbb{Z}{[i]}$ such that $N(z)$ is a prime number then $z$ is irreducible.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2004018/prove-if-z-in-mathbbzi-such-that-nz-is-a-prime-number-then-z-is)

$a+bi$ is irreducible. $\Bbb{Z}[i]$ is an integral domain and $a+bi$ is irreducible in $\Bbb{Z}[i]$ so somehow its a field by a theorem (which theorem I am not  sure, need to fix this)

$$ \begin{aligned}
a+bi &\equiv0 \mod(a+bi)
\\ a & \equiv b *i \mod(a+bi)
\\ [a] &= [bi]
\end{aligned}$$

so $z\in \Bbb{Z}[i]$ $z=\alpha+\beta i$

$$\begin{aligned}
z+(a+bi)\equiv [z] =[\alpha + \beta i]=\text{ stuff I need to think more}
\end{aligned} $$

somehow that is $\Bbb{Z}_p$ so $\frac{\Bbb{Z}[i]}{a+bi} \cong \Bbb{Z}_p$ being a field.

Comment: THE JOHNS HOPKINS UNIVERSITY
Faculty of Arts and Sciences
FINAL EXAM - FALL SESSION 2006
110.401 - ADVANCED ALGEBRA I. they just use it. I dont have a proof and could prob use an isomorphism theorem of rings to prove  it

Comment: Don't they teach you TeX at THE JOHNS HOPKINS UNIVERSITY Faculty of Arts and Sciences?

Comment: Here are two more duplicates: [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/373073/quotient-rings-of-gaussian-integers), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23358/quotient-ring-of-gaussian-integers).  As in the linked posts, you can show that $\mathbb{Z}[i]/(a+bi) \cong \mathbb{Z}/(a^2 + b^2)$ and then note that $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ is a field with $p$ elements.