# Argument and motivation behind maps used in finding inrreducibles in an integral domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, field-theory, finite-fields

I present the solution to a past question that I didn't had time to understand even on a superficial level.
[image]

I am unable to understand the classical argument employed in the methods for finding irreducibles. I have stared at this for 5 whole hours.

Here's what I know: 21=7.3=$(1+2\sqrt{-5})(1-2\sqrt{-5})$

The factors 7,3, $(1+2\sqrt{-5}) and (1-2\sqrt{-5})$ are all non-unit and clearly are non-zero.
They satisfy ONE condition for the definition for an element/ factor to be an irreducible.

To ensure the factors are irreducibles, we need to ensure that there exists two elements in the Integral domain $\mathbb{Z}\left [ \sqrt{-5} \right ]$ such that a factor, say 3 = xy where x,y are elements in $\mathbb{Z}\left [ \sqrt{-5} \right ]$. It suffice for us to ensure that either x or y are units.

But in the solution, the argument assumes that x and y are non-units. Is this a proof by contradiction?
Also, why it it necessary for a map N commonly used in determining primes, irreducibles and associates to exists?
I'm extremely confused when authors toggle between the image of the elements under the map N and the elements itself in the integral domain.

Comment: $ 3 = xy\,\overset{N}\Rightarrow\, 9 = (Nx)(Ny)$ so $\,Nx,Ny\neq 1\,\Rightarrow\, Nx = 3 = Ny,\,$ contradiction.

Comment: Why can't it be N(x)=9 and N(y)=1?

Comment: Because $Ny = 1\,\Rightarrow\,y$ is a unit but, by hypothesis, x,y are nonunits in the nontrivial factorization $3 = xy\ $ witnessing reducibility of $3.\ \ $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it *is* a proof by contradiction. An element $z ∈ ℤ[\sqrt{-5}]$ is reducible if there are nonunits $x, y ∈ ℤ[\sqrt{-5}]$ such that $z = xy$.

If, for any pair of non-units $x, y ∈ ℤ[\sqrt{-5}]$, it is impossible that $z = xy$, then $z$ must be irreducible.

This is what is done in the quoted solution for $z = 3$, $z = 7$ and $z = 1 ± 2\sqrt{-5}$: They assume that there are *nonuints* $x, y ∈ ℤ[\sqrt{-5}]$ with $z = xy$ and find a contradiction.

To reach the contradiction, they throw $N$ at the assumption $z = xy$ to get $N(z) = N(x)N(y)$. This is an equation in $ℤ$ where we know unique prime factorisation is possible, so it’s easier to reason here. This why this is done.

Such a neat map $N \colon A → ℤ$ doesn’t exist for general integral domains $A$.  Here, in this case, you can think of it as coming from the square of the absolute value $ℂ → ℤ, z ↦ |z|^2$.  So we use that the domain in question $A$ is actually embedded in a ring we already know a lot about: $ℂ$.

(More generally, the $N$ stands for *norm*. Whenever $L / K$ is a field extension, any element $a ∈ L$ acts as a $K$-linear map on $L$ by right-multplication $(~·a) \colon L → L,~x ↦ xa$, so it makes sense to look at its determinant – which is called its norm: $N(a) = \det (~·a)$.)

Comment: I'm seeing the big picture now. The first sentence in the outset of your post is a contrapositivity of the definition. That helps a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that the map $N$ is $\rm\color{#c00}{multiplicative}$ $\,N(xy) = (Nx)(Ny),\,$ and, furthermore, that  $\,\color{#0a0}{x\mid Nx}.\,$ Then $\,Na$ irreducible $\,\Rightarrow\, a$ irreducible, since

$\ \ a = bc\,\color{#c00}\Rightarrow\, Na = Nb\, Nc,\ $ so $\,Nb\,$ or $\,Nc\,$ is a unit, say $Nc.\ $ Then $\,\color{#0a0}{c\mid Nc}\mid 1\,$ so $\,c\,$ is unit.

Yours is special case $\,Na = a\bar a =  {\rm Norm}(a)$

**Remark** $ $ The key idea is that multiplicative maps preserve multiplicative properties (which is brought to the fore in *divisor theory*). Above we pullback the "atom" (irreducible) property  along the multiplicative norm map $\,N$.

In fact much of the multiplicative structure of a number ring is reflected in its monoid of norms. For example, in many favorable contexts (e.g. Galois) a number ring enjoys unique factorization iff its monoid of norms does. See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/95015/242) for further discussion, including literature references (Bumby and Dade, Lettl, Coykendall).