# Irreducible element in a Integral domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, unique-factorization-domains

Show that $3+\sqrt{-7}$ is an irreducible element in the integral domain $Z[-7]$

My approach.
Equation 1: 
$$ 3+\sqrt{-7} = (a+b\sqrt{-7} )(c+d\sqrt{-7})$$
Equation 2:
$$ 3-\sqrt{-7} = (a-b\sqrt{-7} )(c-d\sqrt{-7})$$
Multiplying above equations
$$ 16 = (a^2+7b^2)(c^2+7d^2)$$
Possible solutions  of the above equation in this ring are
$$ 16 = 16*1 $$ 
$$ 16 = 1*16 $$
$$ 16 = 2*8 $$
$$ 16 = 8*2 $$
$$ 16 = 4*4 $$
First & second solutions would make one of the elements as unit. Hence ignoring them.
3rd and fourth solutions are not possible.
Fifth solution is possible when $ a=2,c=2,b=0 $ and $  d=0$. 
Now I have two questions.

1. fifth solution is not satisfying the first equation. why?
2. How come the term $3+\sqrt{-7}$ is irreducible if we can express it as a product of two non-unit terms.

Comment: You get $a=\pm 2$ and $c=\pm 2$ and if you put these back in the original equations you will see that they don't provide factors.

Comment: You can compare your ideas with many similar questions and answers here about this topic, e.g., [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/94999/irreducible-in-mathbbz-sqrt-5) etc.

Comment: Your inferences are not *bidrectional*, they only prove the $(\Rightarrow)$ direction, i.e. if such a factorization exists then $a,b$ satisfy said equations. The reverse direction needn't hold, i.e. solutions for $a,b$ needn't yield a factorization, i.e. the solutions $\,a,b\,$ may be "extraneous". So you need to verify that those *possible* solutions are *actual* solutions, i.e. you need to also (dis)prove the reverse direction $(\Leftarrow)$

Comment: As for $(2)$ you didn't actually factor it since you didn't verify that the possible solutions are actual solutions (they aren't).