# How to prove that 3 is irreducible in $Z[i\sqrt{5}]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I tried to write $3 = (a+bi \sqrt{5})(c+di \sqrt{5})$ and got:

- $ac -5bd = 3$
- $ad + bc = 0$

But I couldn't show that one of the two terms is identity.

How to proceed?

Comment: Are you familiar with the norm map $N \colon \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}] \to \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: I think that no.

Comment: With norms, maybe?

Comment: I will try read about this in a book.

Comment: The norm map is a valuable tool for answering this kind of question. In your case, it can be defined very explicitly: it is the map $N \colon \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}] \to \mathbb{Z}$ defined by $N(a+b\sqrt{-5}) = a^{2}+5b^{2}$. (It is just the restriction of the usual complex norm to $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$.) A start towards your question would be to show that $N$ is multiplicative, i.e. $N(xy) = N(x)N(y)$ for any $x, y \in \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$. The next step would be characterizing elements $x \in \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ such that $N(x) = 1$.

Comment: To make the introduction of the norm maybe seem less opaque: the main obstruction to this question is that factorization in $R := \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ is not so nice. In particular, $R$ is not a UFD; your question is a step on the way to showing this, by observing that $6 = 2 \cdot 3 = (1+\sqrt{-5})(1-\sqrt{-5})$. Introducing the norm $N$ allows us to transport factorization questions in $R$ to related factorization questions in $\mathbb{Z}$, where we have a very powerful theory of factorization.

Answer (score 1):

The equations you have are a linear system for $(c,d)$. The solution is
$$
c =  \frac{3a}{a^2+5b^2}, \quad
d = -\frac{3b}{a^2+5b^2}
$$
We may assume that $a\ge0$ and so $c\ge0 $.

If $a=0$ then $c=0$. But then $3=-5bd$, which cannot happen in $\mathbb Z$.

Thus $c\ge 1$ and so $3a-a^2 \ge 5b^2$. The maximum value of $3x-x^2$ is $2.25$ and so $b^2 \le 0.45$. Since $b$ is an integer, we must have $b=0$ and so $d=0$. But then $ac=3$. Thus, $a+bi \sqrt{5}=1$ or $c+di \sqrt{5}=1$, that is, one of the factors is a unit.

Answer (score 1):

In disguise, the ring is actually $ R = \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$. To show that 3 is irreducible in $R$, we need to show that if $3=\alpha \beta$,  then either $\alpha$ or $\beta$ is a unit. Define a norm function $$N: R \to \mathbb{Z}$$ This is equivalent to showing that either $N(\alpha) = 1$ or $N(\beta) = 1$. A beautiful discussion on how we come to this can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/95015/1110944). Unless given a different norm, it is acceptable to use the field norm given by $$N: \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{-5}] \to \mathbb{Q}\quad \text{ defined by } \quad N(a+b\sqrt{-5}) = a^2 +5b^2$$

Notice that the field norm is multiplicative, that is $N(AB) = N(A)N(B)$. So the work comes down to solving the following equation:
$$9 = N(\alpha) = N(\alpha)N(\beta)$$

Write $\alpha = a+ b\sqrt{-5}$ and $\beta = c + d\sqrt{-5}$, then $N(\alpha) = a^2+5d^2$ and $N(\beta) = c^2+5d^2$.

Doing the algebra comes down to: $$9 = (a^2+ 5b^2)(c^2+5d^2) $$

WLOG, the possible options for $(\alpha, \beta)$ are: $(1,9), (3,3)$. It cannot be $(3,3)$. So, that leaves us with one option: $N(\alpha) = 1$ (or $N(\beta)= 1$).